# How to extract link from html script in python?

Tags: python, html

How can I extract the URL from a script of HTML with Python? 
The HTML provided:

```
function download() {
                window.open('https:somelink.com');
        }
        const text = `&lt;div style=\'position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%;height: 0;overflow: hidden;\'&gt;
&lt;iframe allowfullscreen=\'allowfullscreen\' src=\'URL\' style=\'border: 0;height: 100%;left: 0;position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;\' &gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;`;

function embed() {
                var element = document.getElementById('embed-text');
                console.log(element);
                element.innerHTML = text

        }
```

Desired output will be:

```
https://somelink.com
```

Any help will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex like this:

```js
var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/; // the regex
// your string
var input = "&lt;div style=\'position: relative;padding-bottom: 56.25%;height: 0;overflow: hidden;\'&gt;&lt;iframe allowfullscreen=\'allowfullscreen\' src=\" https://my-url.com/test \" style=\'border: 0;height: 100%;left: 0;position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;\' &gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;/div&gt;";

console.log(input.match(urlRegex)[1]); // use regex and lot result
```